# Can't login to newly created webapp / site coll

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, authentication, central-administration

I have created a new Farm sp2013 onpremise.

I have two virtual machines (VMs),one with domain controller/AD and one with a sharepoint installation. After the CA configuration wizard there is a webapp on http:// that works fine. I have created a site coll there and can login.

Now when I create another site with hostname "another-site.local.com"  I can create it and create a site coll on it. But when I visit "http://another-site.local.com I get that login-popup and it keeps coming at me as if the user/pwd is wrong

I have added myself to farm admins and (web app -->user policies-->full perm)
I am administrator at site collection
I know user/pwd is correct. 
I have added an entry in the hosts-file (127.0.0.1 another-site.local.com)

Comment: Sounds like a loopback check issue. Are you trying to access the site from the server? https://nikpatel.net/2013/09/05/disable-the-loopback-check-for-specific-host-names-on-all-sharepoint-web-and-application-servers/

Comment: Hi Derek! Yes you are correct :) Thanks. If you post same answer in an answer I can set it to correct answer and youll get the creds for this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved by disabling loopback check. Refer this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shyjumohan/disable-loop-back-check-in-windows-server-2012/

FYI,

Microsoft has introduced **a security feature** in 2003 Server **to prevent attacks** on Windows servers. This feature will prevent a web application access from the host server with a fully qualified domain name. During the SharePoint installation this is one of the issues that needs to be addressed.

---

Thank you very much **@Derek Gusoff** for your reference: https://nikpatel.net/2013/09/05/disable-the-loopback-check-for-specific-host-names-on-all-sharepoint-web-and-application-servers/